# F#: referential transparency of `nameof` operator

Tags: scala, functional-programming, f#, macros, referential-transparency

I'm not very knowledgeable on F#, but I like functional programming, so I've used F# as inspiration for some of my personal projects.

I was recently reading a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-50) on new features of F#, and I liked the one part of the `nameof` operator.

However, after diving deep into the idea, I realized it may not be referentially transparent... As in, the expression can be replaced by its value, and vice versa, and it'd just work.

So...

```ml
let sum = +;
nameof (sum)
```

Should return the same as

```ml
nameof (+)
```

But they don't...

So... Is that lack of referential transparency intentional? How would Functional Programmers reconcile that with the principles of FP?

While writing this question I realized that `nameof` behaves like a macro, and therefore, the same question holds for macros.

How do FP Programmers reconcile the non referential transparency of macros, with FP principles?

Comment: referential transparency means everytime you evaluate the same expression you get the same answer. You have 2 different expressions

Answer (score 5):

`nameof` isn't a function or operator in the traditional sense. It is a metaprogramming feature that emits a string representation of a name as-determined by how the F# compiler does name resolution. That's also why in editors, it is colored as a keyword instead of any other F# function.

The following:

```
let sum = +;
nameof (sum)
```

Yielding `sum` is not only be design, but precisely the kind of behavior that F# and .NET programmers expect from this feature, especially since this is (more or less) what C# does as well. I personally think it would be very unexpected for something called `nameof` to not give me literally the name of what I am passing into it.